# CSS Colours not displaying

Tags: html, css, colors

I'm really new to using HTML and CSS and I'm trying to create a rectangular box -

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesAgg.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testing the class page</h1>

<ul>
{% for book in books %}
    <div id ="bookInfo" style = "display">
        <div>
            <text class= "text" id = "bookTitle">{{ book.title|safe }}</text></br>
            <text class= "text" id= "bookAuthor">by {{ book.author|safe }}</text></br>
        </div>
    </div>


{% endfor %}
</ul>

</body> 

</html>
```

My css code is here -

```
#bookInfo {
    float:right;
    width:700px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#dd2424;
    padding-left:12px;
    padding-top:17px;
}
```

why doesn't my html page display the coloured rectangle?

Thanks!

EDIT-
I've included all the advice below and it still doesn't work - however, when I view the page through firebug, it says that there are no rules(there's some 404 error, despite the fact that I have the style sheets) - I think this is the problem- how do I fix it?

Comment: What is the complete files for the two style sheets?

Comment: It's hard to debug HTML code when you've posted a template file rather than actual HTML. Please post the rendered HTML. (Also, multiple identical IDs are invalid, and quite possibly the cause of your problem.)

Comment: Also, the `style="display"` sets the display to an unspecified value. Try `style="display: block;"`.

Answer (score 2):

IDs are supposed to be unique in an HTML page. For formatting multiple elements on a page with similar rules, use the `class` attribute. Try to change the `id` attribute on your `div` to a `class`. Also change your CSS fro `#bookInfo` to `.bookInfo`.

Also, `<ul>` starts an unordered list. The *only* tag type that is allowed directly inside of it is a `<li>` which creates an entry in that list. `<div>`'s are not allowed here. You could either change the `<div>` to a `<li>` or just drop the `<ul>` altogether, depending on your actual semantic desires.

Another wrong usage are your `</br>` tags. If a tag starts with `</` it is considered a closing tag, as opposed to `<br/>` which is an empty tag and is probably what you meant here.

As a final advise to style, you should stick to all lower classes and IDs.It makes debugging much easier and looks better.

Comment: I tried it with .bookInfo, it still doesn't work - 
also, regarding the comment on <ul>- why does the text inside of the second div tags show up?

Answer (score 1):

You have few errors in your code.

1. the id attribute of an element must be unique across the whole html page. I assume that there will be more books than one. I recommend you to use attibute `class="bookInfo"` instead of id. The corresponding css selector could be: `.bookInfo {}` (notice the dot at the start)
2. value of style attribute here: `<div id ="bookInfo" style = "display">` is invalid. If you wanted to set css display property, you should assign some value to it. Otherwise, you should delete the whole attribute.
3. You are missing `<li>` elements of the `<ul>`.

The correct HTML code should look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesAgg.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testing the class page</h1>

<ul>
{% for book in books %}
  <li>
    <div class ="bookInfo">
        <div>
            <text class= "text" id = "bookTitle">{{ book.title|safe }}</text></br>
            <text class= "text" id= "bookAuthor">by {{ book.author|safe }}</text></br>
        </div>
    </div>
  </li>

{% endfor %}
</ul>

</body> 

</html>
```

and css:

```
.bookInfo {
    float:right;
    width:700px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#dd2424;
    padding-left:12px;
    padding-top:17px;
}
```

Also make sure, that css file is really loaded with the page. 
I recommnend usage of Firebug (Firefox extension) or Chrome dev tools... Right click anywhere on page - inspect element. Very helpful.

Comment: interesting- in firebug it says that there are no rules- that could be the problem- if it is why is it saying that?

Comment: If there are no css rules assigned to element, you should look if the css file is loaded (firebug net panel). Is the `style2.css` and `stylesAgg.css` in same directory as the html file?

Comment: Regarding to your edit. The 404 error for css files is obviously the problem :-) How do you access the html page? Just by file protocol (file://)? Or you have some http server serving these files for you? If you or your server is running on unix like os, you should check the file names, because they are case sensitive.